# DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement Error in Blazor WASM

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, blazor, webassembly

I am work on a Blazor Webassembly hosted app that use JWT authentication/authorization. When I run the project and try to register or login, I take this error.[image]

How should I catch this error.

```
//ConfigureServices
    

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
               
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["jwt:key"])),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero

            }); ;
```

//Configure Method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();
                endpoints.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
```

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://medium.com/@st.mas29/microsoft-blazor-web-api-with-jwt-authentication-part-1-f33a44abab9d) may helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how it work exactly but you should pass a string parameter "auth" when create Claimprinciple as shown below:

```
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim( ClaimTypes.Name, "newbie"),
        new Claim( ClaimTypes.Role, "guest")
    }, "auth"));

    return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
}
```

The string could be anything.